OfficeJS API: Tracked Changes and File Comparison
I am currently using the compare() function to compare two files, and when the changes appear on the Word side, I want to use getTrackedChanges() to retrieve those changes. However, when I log it using console.log, the items array is empty.
I want to use compare to compare file 1 and file 2. When I set file 1 as the current file, I can retrieve the changes in the items, but when I set file 2 as the current file, I am unable to do so.
const compareFiles = async () => {
    const createdBy = “name”
    try {
      await Word.run(async (context) => {
        const options = {
          authorName: createdBy,
        };
        context.document.compare(“https:demo.blob.test”, options);
        await context.sync();
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error: ", error);
    }
};


const getTrackedChanges = async () => {
      await Word.run(async (context) => {
        const body = context.document.body;
        const trackedChanges = body.getTrackedChanges();
        trackedChanges.load("items");
        await context.sync();
     }
};

Does anyone have a solution that could help me?

Wouldn't you at least need that https: to be https:// ?
